# Помогите с регуляркой, как удалить часть строки после цифр?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть вот такие строки.

```
site1.com/component/k2/item/9-swing-swing.html
site1.com/component/k2/item/9/9-swing-swing/fsdf
si-te1.com/com-ponent/k2/item/85555-vnss-logo.php
si-te1.com/com-ponent/k2/item/8/
si0te1.com/component/k2/item/2-mercedes-elegant.html
s--ite1.com/component/k2/item/15-lacoste-concept.html
site1.com/component/k2/item/51235-incorruptible.html
si0te1.com/component/k2/item/2mercedes-elegant.html
```

Как обреать все что идет после последних цифр в адресе?
Получится должно так

```
site1.com/component/k2/item/9
site1.com/component/k2/item/9
si-te1.com/com-ponent/k2/item/85555
si-te1.com/com-ponent/k2/item/8
si0te1.com/component/k2/item/2
s--ite1.com/component/k2/item/15
site1.com/component/k2/item/51235
si0te1.com/component/k2/item/2
```

Вот часть регулярки `(/k2/item/[0-9]*)` мне нужно удалить всё что с права от неё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найти `(.*\/k2\/item\/\d+).*`, заменить на `$1`.
[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/7imOXC/1)

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Можете подправить что бы во второй строке удалило ```/9``` ?

Comment: Не сразу понял, что нужно, т.к. заголовок противоречит результату. Скорректировал.